# Apple Safari considers autofill as empty input

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a HTML form with an input control. Attached to this input control I have a JavaScript validation script.

Now I use Safari's autofill to enter stored user name and password.

Problem is that regardless of whatever event I attach my JS validation script to, I cannot make JS believe the input control has any value entry. It keeps validating the input as if it has no value. If I click into the input and add a space at the end, everything suddenly is visible to JS.

Someone who knows how to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is for security reasons. Imagine what a JavaScript could do, if it could read the automatically filled password-fields. It would be possible to read passwords from the keychain without any confirmation by the user.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to use this function automatically. It gives you a list of choices. When you click your choice the inputs are filled with data. However, Safari seems to think the content of the inputs have been deleted not filled in.